# How to open both camera and video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

How i can open both Video capture And  and Image capture Camera from One Button like IPhone Default Camera  where i can slide from video to image click. is their any third party for that please help?

Comment: You will need to make custom image / video capture and not use UIImagePIcker

Comment: Is their any example Or third party ?

Answer (score 0):

You've to make your custom camera for that and handle the both cases [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112).
or there is a third party that do the same [check it](https://github.com/Awalz/SwiftyCam).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I was looking for we need to set mediaType if both bot photo and video mode is required in a single action.

```
    let  picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = type
    picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image","public.movie"]
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Happy Coding :)